# smtp login in linux terminal

Tags: bash, email

For testing reasons,I want to lofin to a smtp server from the linux terminal. I found [this example](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP-Auth#Beispiel) on how to log in within a openssl connection. But I want a single command to login the smtp server and not an interactive dialog, where I have to type additional commands.

TL:DR How can I login to a smtp server with a single bash command?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [swaks](http://www.jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for a 3rd party testing application with TLS, AUTH support exactly what `swaks` is.

#### Install Swaks

```sh
$ pacman -S swaks         # ArchLinux
$ apt install swaks       # Debian/Ubuntu
$ dnf install swaks       # Fedora
```

#### Using Swaks

Taking a quick look at `man swaks` or [swaks' latest documents](http://jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/latest/doc/ref.txt), will give us quite the understandment about how the operation can be done:

```sh
$ swaks --to reciever@domain.com --from sender@domain.com \
--auth-user sender@domain.com --auth-password Th1s15SendersPassword \
--auth CRAM-MD5 --header-X-Test "test email"
```

Refer to [swaks website](http://jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/index.html) for full information.